# Can't get gray scale of an image in java

Tags: java, image-processing, io, grayscale

I have a problem with getting gray scale of a .jpg file. I am trying to create a new .jpg file as gray scaled but I am just copying the image nothing more. Here is my code:

```
package training01;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GrayScale {
    BufferedImage image;
    int width;
    int height;
    public GrayScale() {
        try {
            File input = new File("digital_image_processing.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
            width = image.getWidth();
            height = image.getHeight();
            for(int i = width;i < width;i++) {
                for(int j = height;j < height;j++) {
                    Color c =  new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
                    int red = c.getRed();
                    int green = c.getGreen();
                    int blue = c.getBlue();
                    int val = (red+green+blue)/3;
                    Color temp = new Color(val,val,val);
                    image.setRGB(i, j, temp.getRGB());
                }
            }
            File output = new File("digital_image_processing1.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GrayScale gs = new GrayScale();
    }
}
```

Comment: As JPEG is stored (typically) as YCbCr, you can do this a lot faster by just decoding the Y channel and use that as the gray image directly. ImageIO supports doing this, by setting the appropriate destination type on the `ImageReadParam` and pass that to `ImageReader.read(index, param)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the following.  Start your i and j at 0.

```
      for(int i = width;i < width;i++) {  
         for(int j = height;j < height;j++) {
```

However, here is a faster way to do it.  Write it to a new BufferedImage object that is set for gray scale.

```
      image = ImageIO.read(input);
      width = image.getWidth();
      height = image.getHeight();
      bwImage = new BufferedImage(width,
            height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
      Graphics g = bwImage.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
```

Then save the bwImage.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code, is that it won't loop, because you initialize `i, j` to `width, height` which is already greater than the exit condition of the `for` loops (`i < width, j < height`). Start iterating at 0 by initializing `i` and `j` to `0`, and your code will work as intended.

For better performance, you also want to change the order of the loops. As `BufferedImage`s are stored as a continuous array, row by row, you will utilize the CPU cache much better if you loop over the x axis (row) in the inner loop.

Side note: I also suggest renaming `i` and `j` to `x` and `y` for better readability.

Finally, your method of converting RGB to gray by averaging the colors will work, but is not the most common way to convert to gray scale, as the human eye does not perceive the intensities of the colors as the same. See [Wikipedia on gray scale conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale) for a better understanding of correct conversion and the theory behind it.

---

However, all of this said, for JPEG images stored as YCbCr (the most common way to store JPEGs), there is a much faster, memory efficient and simpler way of converting the image to gray scale, and that is simply reading the Y (luminance) channel of the JPEG and use that as gray scale directly.

Using Java and ImageIO, you can do it like this:

```
public class GrayJPEG {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(args[0]))) {
            ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream).next(); // Will throw exception if no reader available

            try {
                reader.setInput(stream);
                ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

                // The QnD way, just specify the gray type directly
                //param.setDestinationType(ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY));

                // The very correct way, query the reader if it supports gray, and use that
                Iterator<ImageTypeSpecifier> types = reader.getImageTypes(0);
                while (types.hasNext()) {
                    ImageTypeSpecifier type = types.next();

                    if (type.getColorModel().getColorSpace().getType() == ColorSpace.TYPE_GRAY) {
                        param.setDestinationType(type);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                BufferedImage image = reader.read(0, param);

                ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", new File(args[0] + "_gray.jpg"));

            }
            finally {
                reader.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```